# dynamic_cast и поле

Tags: c++

Возник такой вопрос у меня есть `map <string, WarShip *>` где `WarShip` это указатель на экземпляр класса, `WarShip` это класс всех допустим кораблей в котором наследуются ромбовидно 3 корабля других,но каждый корабль имеет своё отличие, и поле которым он отличается, как мне через `dynamic_cast` обратится к этому полю, определённого корабля в `map` ? Вот к примеру я знаю что это авианосец ибо в нём есть поля которые указывают на наличие мест для самолётов, а в крейсере этого поля нету, но мне нужно допустим изменить наличие мест(модифицировать) как мне обратится к этому полю ?

Вот допустим я добавляю корабль

```
MainGroup.TableCarryGroup.insert(
    pair<string, WarShip *>(CALLSIGN, 
                            new Cruiser(HP,SPD,SCF,givenWeapon,
                                        QOCM,givenHuman,NAME_SHIP,IACarryShip,
                                        MainGroup.countCAPS,MainGroup.countWEA‌​PONS)));
```

Далее мне нужно вернуть всю информацию об этом корабле, но `Cruiser` - наследник `WarShip`. Имеет своё специфическое поле под названием `string InfoAboutCarryShip`.

```
if(SHIP->type_ship == 1)
{ 
    Cruiser *cruiser = dynamic_cast<Cruiser*>(SHIP); 
    cout << "16.Information about carrying ship"
         << cruiser->infoAboutCarryShip << endl; 
}
```

вот таким образом я хочу вывести данное поле что я делаю не правильно?

при использовании `static_cast` выдало такую ошибку:

> error: cannot convert from pointer to base class 'warship::WarShip' to
>   pointer to derived class 'cruiser::Cruiser' because the base is
>   virtual Cruiser *cruiser = static_cast(SHIP);

Comment: так как обычная угадайка не дала желаемого результата, думаю это хорошее время создать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, `dynamic_cast` для выполнения downcast применим только к *полиморфным* типам. Ваш тип `WarShip` - полиморфен? Если нет, то никакой `dynamic_cast` тут не применим.

Во-вторых, если вы действительно "точно знаете", какой тип имеет данный объект, то задачу решит `static_cast`. У него нет требования полиморфности. Но и проверку правильности приведения (как это делает `dynamic_cast`) он выполнить не может, так что тут вы должны делать downcast на свой страх и риск. Также `static_cast` не сможет сделать downcast через виртуальное наследование, если оно вдруг у вас есть.

В-третьих, если тип все-таки полиморфен, то может быть вопрос можно решить без приведения типа вообще? Ваш вопрос обладает гигантским потенциалом быть XY-проблемой: вы пытаетесь выяснить, как выполнить downcast, чтобы доступиться к полю класса-наследника, хотя на самом деле полиморфизм для того и предназначен, чтобы вам этого не нужно было делать.

В вашем случае (настолько, насколько его можно понять из приведенной вами информации), класс корабля сам должен уметь выдавать информацию о себе в предоставленный поток при помощи какого-то виртуального метода

```
class WarShip 
{
  ...
  virtual void WriteSpecificInfo(std::ostream &strm) = 0;
  ...
};

class Cruiser : public WarShip
{
  ...
  virtual void WriteSpecificInfo(std::ostream &strm) override
  {
    strm << "16.Information about carrying ship" << infoAboutCarryShip;
  }
  ...
};

...
SHIP->WriteSpecificInfo(std::cout);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

И никаких `if (SHIP->type_ship == 1)` и приведений.

Comment: @AnT взгляните пожалуйста снова на поставленный мною вопрос)

Comment: @VTT Добавил в основной вопрос

Comment: вы оказались правы, я думал можно просто как то сделать через dynamic cast

Comment: @Destroyer: Через `dynamic cast` *можно* сделать. Достаточно добавить в ваш класс `WarShip` хоть одну виртуальную функцию. Но сам подход - ущербен.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, допустим, что этот авианосец - `Carrier` - наследник `WarShip`. А `w` - указатель на `WarShip`, сохраненный в вашем `map`.

```
Carrier * c = dynamic_cast<Carrier*>(w);
if (c) // На тот случай, если это не авианосец
{
    c->getPlanes(); // Или что там вам надо...
}
```

Примерно так. Понятно, что должен быть включен RTTI, а у `WarShip` быть виртуальные функции...

**Update**
Раз вы храните поле типа корабля (не нравится мне ваш дизайн... но хозяин - барин...) - то приводите с помощью `static_cast`:

```
if(SHIP->type_ship == 1)
{ 
    Cruiser *cruiser = static_cast<Cruiser*>(SHIP); 
    cout << "16.Information about carrying ship"
         << cruiser->infoAboutCarryShip << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Выдало данную ошибку

cannot dynamic_cast 'SHIP' (of type 'class warship::WarShip*') to type 'class cruiser::Cruiser*' (source type is not polymorphic)
             Cruiser *c = dynamic_cast<Cruiser*>(SHIP);

Comment: @Destroyer: Почему вы тогда вообще завели речь о `dynamic_cast`? Откуда вообще взялся `dynamic_cast` в вашем вопросе?

Comment: См. обновленный ответ...

Comment: @Harry при использовании static выдаёт ошибку)

Comment: Ну я же не знаю весь ваш код. Значит, что-то не так, как вы описали.